# tor-privoxy error: connection refused

Tags: ruby, proxy, tor

I'm trying to use [tor-privoxy](https://github.com/pirj/tor-privoxy) to switch my IP address.

I copied the code from the README, for the most part:

```
require 'tor-privoxy'

agent ||= TorPrivoxy::Agent.new '127.0.0.1', '', {8123 => 9051} do |agent|
  sleep 5
  p agent
  p "New IP is #{agent.ip}"
end
```

But when I run it, I got this error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:641:in `rescue in connection_for': connection refused: 127.0.0.1:8123 (Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:589:in `connection_for'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:259:in `fetch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:440:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tor-privoxy-0.1.1/lib/tor-privoxy/agent.rb:38:in `ip'
    from C:/Users/Lap/Dropbox/Programming_Stuff/Ruby_Stuff/Code/tor and socksify stuff/torPrivoxyTest.rb:6:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tor-privoxy-0.1.1/lib/tor-privoxy/agent.rb:11:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tor-privoxy-0.1.1/lib/tor-privoxy/agent.rb:11:in `initialize'
    from C:/Users/Lap/Dropbox/Programming_Stuff/Ruby_Stuff/Code/tor and socksify stuff/torPrivoxyTest.rb:3:in `new'
    from C:/Users/Lap/Dropbox/Programming_Stuff/Ruby_Stuff/Code/tor and socksify stuff/torPrivoxyTest.rb:3:in `<main>'
[Finished in 8.5s with exit code 1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the wrong port. Privoxy uses port 8118 (8123 is polipo). Tor on the other side uses either 9050 (plain Tor) or 9150 (Tor browser bundle). So if you change your settings the communication should work.

Comment: I changed the first number to 8118. The second to 9150. I still get the same error. I have Tor browser in a folder on my desktop. I'm using Windows.